# Access ROS node in hardware_interface

Tags: ros, ros2, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am transferring my robot hardware interface to ROS2. In my ROS1 hardware interface, I used a publisher to publish additional information like the current controller temperature, limit switches status etc. However, in ROS2, I could not find a way to access the node from the hardware interface plugin, so creating a publisher is not possible anymore.

Is it possible to get access to the node in a hardware interface plugin? Or, if not, what is the preferred way to communicating additional hardware state information in ROS2?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414029/access-ros-node-in-hardware_interface/) by [rick95](https://answers.ros.org/users/144264/rick95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, "nothing has changed" wrt the best / accepted practices in `ros2_control` vs `ros_control`. See #q375296 for a previous Q&A which discussed a similar topic (related: [ros-controls/ros2_control#740](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/740), although that issue asks whether using pub-sub for interaction with the actual hw would be acceptable/ok -- it links to the ROS Answers Q&A though).

Summarising: the cleanest way to publish the kinds of information you mention would be from `ros2_control` *broadcasters* (used to be called *controllers*, but they only published information, so the name was (finally) changed).

You could take a look at [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver) which follows that recommendation for things like GPIO and some other status information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rick95](https://answers.ros.org/users/144264/rick95/) on 2023-04-05**:
Thanks for your answer! So, if I understand it right, I need to add additional state interfaces (`hardware_interface::StateInterface`) for the additional state information. Then the `joint_state_broadcaster` publishes the additional state information on a topic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-04-05**:
Almost.

You'd add your own custom hardware interfaces, for which you then would need to implement your own custom broadcasters.

The default `joint_state_broadcaster` would only "know" how to publish `JointState` messages. It can't do anything with your custom state information.

> I used a publisher to publish additional information like the current controller temperature, limit switches status etc.

for limit switches specifically, you might be able to reuse the GPIO infrastructure in `ros2_control`. That is, if you don't necessarily need any higher level semantics for that (ie: instead of "pin 3 is high", you'd want "limit switch of motor/joint 'elbow' is high").